# How to disable automatic initialization of Unity Advertisements?

Tags: unity-game-engine, initialization, ads

I would like to have manual initialization of Advertisements so that I initialize them only when I want them to be shown. I want to avoid unnecessary fetching of Ads. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out when you enable Ads from editor's built in services, you have no control over it's initialization. I downloaded the Ads SDK from Asset store, everything seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

code_guri. You should use

AdvertisementSettings.initializeOnStartup = false

to prevent auto Initialization. You can use Initialize(string gameId) to start it manually.

Here is the docs:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Advertisements.AdvertisementSettings-initializeOnStartup.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Advertisements.Advertisement.Initialize.html

Good luck :)

Comment: AdvertisementSettings.initializeOnStartup is not working for me, It shows compiler error. I am doing 'using UnityEngine.Advertisements', it's still not letting me use it. My unity editor's version is up to date.

Comment: Ok, I'll do some research on the documentation and come back to you when I find some answer :)

Comment: By the way, can you show me the compiler error, please?

Comment: It says 'AdvertisementSettings' does not exist in the current context, however it should be defined under UnityEngine.Advertisements.

Comment: This issue had driving me crazy, wanted to share solution with you. As it turns out when you enable Ads from editor built in services, you have no control over it's initialization. I downloaded the Ads SDK , everything seems fine now.

Comment: Nice job code_guri! Thanks for sharing.
Congrats :D